# Adding list elements as a columns of a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I was wondering if there is a possibility to add list elements as columns of a data frame.

e.g. I have defined a list

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

and I would like to add it as the columns of my data frame

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 2500))
x <- c("P", "B", "R")
colnames(df) <- x
```

My data frame has already values included in columns P, B & R.

Now I would like to add my list a as new columns without any values (alternative it could also be 0) in each of the rows.

In the end my data frame should have the columns P, B, R, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I was thinking about doing it with 'cbind()' or addressing the data frame directly but this does not seem to work. Can anyone please help me on that?

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
df[as.character(a)] <- NA

> head(df)
   P  B  R  1  2  3  4  5
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Just note that having column names starting with a number is not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

We can also wrap with `paste0` to convert to character

```
df[paste0(a)] <- NA
```

---

An option with `add_column`

```
library(tibble)
add_column(df, !!! setNames(rep(list(NA), length(a)), a))
```

We can specify the `.after` or `.before` to add the columns in a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach by [@sindri_baldur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64170987/12158757) is sufficiently simple already.

Here is another base R option but a bit more complicated

```
cbind(df,setNames(rep(list(NA),length(a)),a))
```